# How do I disable a specific CPU core at boot?

Tags: boot, cpu, multi-core

I have a 16 core Intel Xeon processor that successfully boots into the BIOS and GRUB, but fails to load Ubuntu (or any operating system). It turns out that core #14 is the cause of all the issues (discovered after testing each individual core with memtest86). In the BIOS, I can set the system to run with just 2 cores, and the system works in this configuration. But I would like to be able to use 15 out of 16 of the cores. Is there a way to disable only core #14 at boot?

Comment: Not specific core 14, but maybe a workaround: https://stackpointer.io/hardware/how-to-disable-a-cpu-core/126/

Comment: very cool using memtest86 to test each core. I didn't know you could do that, but checked and see the "select core" option.

Comment: Thanks. The problem originally presented itself as failed RAM, and booting into Ubuntu would get stuck at "loading initial ramdisk". But the (parallel) memory test showed all 4 modules as dead, which seemed unlikely. So I tried the round-robin test, which passed until it got to core #14.

Comment: I would get a new CPU. Maybe even contact Intel to see if there is a recall for manufacturing defect and a free one is available.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix : A single package 16 core, 32 thread, Xeon processor is very very expensive. I think what Samyah93 has figured out to be able to continue is brilliant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use of [CPU hotplug](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/cpu_hotplug.html) abilities to achieve your objective. You can boot CPUs 0-13 and then add the others (CPUs 15-27, and 29-31) afterwards.

All Xeon processors have hyper threading, so I assume you mean 16 cores at 2 threads per core, for a total of 32 CPUs. This answer is written, and tested, for a 4 core, 2 threads per core, processor, where core 2 is the bad one.

First, as sudo, edit `/etc/default/grub` and add the maximum boot time CPUs, `maxcpus=`, to your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line. Example for my system:

Was:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=300 cpuidle_sysfs_switch cpuidle.governor=teo"
```

Now:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=300 cpuidle_sysfs_switch cpuidle.governor=teo maxcpus=2"
```

Where I used `maxcpus=2` you would use `maxcpus=14`.

Save a copy of grub first, and run `sudo update-grub` after.
Thus, the system will boot only using cores 0 and 1, and in CPUs 0,1 being on-line:

```
doug@s15:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/online:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/online:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/online:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/online:0
```

Note: For the default Ubuntu kernel configurations CPU 0 is always online, and there is no such thing as:

```
doug@s15:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online
grep: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online: No such file or directory
```

O.K. so now, bring the other desired cores and CPUs on-line:

```
doug@s15:~$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online
1
doug@s15:~$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/online
1
doug@s15:~$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/online
1
doug@s15:~$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/online
```

And check:

```
doug@s15:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/online:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/online:1
```

So now, I have cores 0,1,3 on-line and core 2 offline and 6 CPUs available.
Note that core 0 =  cpus 0 and 4, core 1 = cpus 1 and 5, ...

EDIT 1: For 32 CPUs, perhaps you have multiple nodes (processors), so the core to CPU mapping might be different.

EDIT 2: It may be that the CPUs that are brought on-line after boot default to using the performance governor in the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, which is the kernel configuration default (which gets changed to powersave 1 minute after boot, for the boot enabled CPUs). You might want to check and set all CPU governors to your preference, typically the powersave governor. To check do:

```
grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

To change governors do, for example (notice as root):

```
# for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "powersave" > $file; done
```

Once you have things working the way you want you can automate the additional on-line after boot step (see other questions and answers for "how to").

Note: It seems to me that you should be able to achieve your objective in one boot step via "cpu_possible_mask" manipulation via "possible_cpus=n", but I couldn't get it to work. Someone else might know.

Comment: For anyone with 10 or more cores, the enumeration of online CPUs was a bit confusing. Specifically, CPUs 10-19 were listed before CPU 1 (then CPUs 20-29 before CPU 2, and so on). I found it to be easier to read by doing:
`grep "" /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online`

Comment: @Samyah93 : Of course. Thanks for the feedback. Answer edited.